# Parsing a pattern using regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following patterns:

**"[list of tickets] [] : List of tickets"** Example 1

How can I parse the above strings to validate the pattern below.

`[Jira-Ticket-list] [TAG] : <Some notes>"`

Also how can I parse the tickets and tag out of the string above?

**Expected output:**

**Example 1:**

Tickets = [list of tickets]

Tag = [TAG-0.3.4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.search` to check for the pattern `r'(\[(?:JIRA\-\d+,?)*\])\s+(\[TAG-[\d.]+\])\s+:\s+(.*)$'` and if it matches, `<match>.groups()` would contain the tickets, tag and description

If the regexp pattern is too strict for you, you can use the simple pattern `r'(\[.*?\]) (\[.*?\]) : (.*)$'` instead

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = "[JIRA-1115,JIRA-1917] [TAG-0.3.4] : List of tickets"
>>> tickets, tag, descr = re.search(r'(\[(?:JIRA\-\d+,?)*\])\s+(\[TAG-[\d.]+\])\s+:\s+(.*)$', s).groups()
>>> tickets, tag, descr
('[JIRA-1115,JIRA-1917]', '[TAG-0.3.4]', 'List of tickets')
>>> 
>>> s = "[JIRA-1116] [TAG-0.3.5] : Only 1 ticket now"
>>> tickets, tag, descr = re.search(r'(\[(?:JIRA\-\d+,?)*\])\s+(\[TAG-[\d.]+\])\s+:\s+(.*)$', s).groups()
>>> tickets, tag, descr
('[JIRA-1116]', '[TAG-0.3.5]', 'Only 1 ticket now')
```

Comment: What if instead of the above example I had "[JIRA-1115,JIRA-1917] -[0.3.4] : Some description" In that case without a version and with the '-' inbetween how could I update it?

Comment: The generic pattern `r'(\[.*?\]) -(\[.*?\]) : (.*)$'` would match

Comment: Yes but the '-' can have white spaces before and after. How can I ignore the whitespaces before and after the '-'. For example: "[JIRA-1115,JIRA-1917] -    [0.3.4] :

Comment: Use `\s*` to match the whitespaces.. So `r'(\[.*?\])\s*-\s*(\[.*?\]) : (.*)$'` should work